# What does the __ prefix mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

If you open up XCode (or probably another IDE) and type in `__` you can see a lot of variables which starts with `__`. (in the auto complete box).

Why did the developers add the `_`s in there?

Comment: These names are reserved for use by the C++ implementation.

Comment: I don't know if they applied only C++ (as standalone language), but many frameworks use macros with prefix _, like "_WINDOWS"

Comment: @Joel - `_WINDOWS` is also in the set of reserved names. All names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved.